# com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException in debug azure media service android

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, live-streaming, azure-media-services

I am trying to create live event instance in azure from my android app. 
I import few jar files and run the below code:

```
        LiveEvent liveEvent = manager.liveEvents().define(liveEventName)
                .withExistingMediaservice("stRG", "staccountname")
                .withAutoStart(true)
                .withInput(new LiveEventInput().withStreamingProtocol(LiveEventInputProtocol.RTMP))
                .withEncoding(new LiveEventEncoding().withEncodingType(LiveEventEncodingType.NONE).withPresetName(null))
                .withLocation("East US")
                .withVanityUrl(false)
                .withDescription("Sample LiveEvent for testing")
                .withStreamOptions(streamOptions)
                .create();
```

it is crash with the error of `com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException` when I debugged it. 
any help why, it will be appreciated

---

*******Updated*****  02/08/2020** 
When I ran it in a different work environment (intelliJ) instead of android studio it ran smoothly

Comment: Can you provide more `com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException`  message ?

Comment: only this is what appears and only when I do `evaluate expression` in debug mode. at the console written `Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601',transport: 'socket' ` without the error that I got in `evaluate expression`.  does I need to open the same port in azure and in the localhost? or maybe it is because jar files conflicts like was mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388110/vmdisconnectedexception-while-debugging-android-app? thank you for the responss

Comment: Can you share the libraries you used? Or provide a reference to them in the docs?